# Laravel query - SQL: Get records start new period today

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am stuck in a laravel query. Please take a look and let me know any clue or solution.
Thank you.

This is my problem.

With now: 2019-12-20.

I have a model **People** with a table like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'employee',
    created_at: '2019-11-20',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'employee',
    created_at: '2019-09-20',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: 'employee',
    created_at: '2019-11-25',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    type: 'ceo',
    created_at: '2019-11-20',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    type: 'cfo',
    created_at: '2019-11-27',
  },
]
```

I have to paid for employees every month, on exactly 30th day (period is 30 days).

So my idea is getting records:

- have type `employee`.
- (now - created_at) % 30 = 0.

And this is my codes so far:

```
$people = People::where('type', 'employee')->get();

foreach ($people as $key => $person) {
  $diff_in_days = Carbon::parse($person->created_at)->diffInDays(Carbon::now()) % 30;

  if ($diff_in_days === 0) {
    // paid for this person.
  }
}
```

And I got the result:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'employee',
    created_at: '2019-11-20',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'employee',
    created_at: '2019-09-20',
  },
]
```

I wonder there is any way to get records with fit `created_at` inside the first query.

I think it will maybe look like this.

```
$people = People::where('type', 'employee')
                -> // some codes to compare: (now - created) % 30 === 0
                ->get();

foreach ($people as $key => $person) {
  // paid for this person.
}
```

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You can try -

```
->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(now(), created_at) = 30')
```

[DATEDIFF()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-datediff.aspx)

For other conditions as per comment -

```
DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) > 60

DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) > 90

DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) > 60 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) <= 90
```

Comment: Thank you. It is an important clue for me. I've updated my question, sorry about my mistake. How can I get `employee` created in 60 days ago, 90 days ago,...

Comment: May be `DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) > 60` or `DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) > 90` or `DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) > 60 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) <= 90`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have the solution. ```->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) % 30 = 0')```. You saved my all day.

Answer (score 1):

something like this may be:

```
$people = People::where('type', 'employee')
                ->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), created_at) = 30')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. In `where` clause, I haven't retrieved `$person->created_at` yet. Am I wrong?

Comment: I have made changes!

Comment: Thank you so much. I have the solution. ```->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) % 30 = 0')```. You guys saved my all day.